# Find the eigenvalues of $A^t A$ given the eigenvalues of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let the square matrix $A$ have an eigenvalue $\lambda.$ We may write the following $$A^tAv = A^t\lambda v = \lambda A^t v = \lambda^2 v,$$ given that an eigenvalue of $A$ is also an eigenvalue of it's transpose. I conclude that $\lambda^2$ is an eigenvalue of the symmetric matrix $A^t A.$
Nevertheless, this seems to be false as is shown by the following example:
\begin{equation*}
A = \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 \\
0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
Its eigenvalues are $2$ and $1$, while the matrix
\begin{equation*}
A^t A = \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 \\
1 & 5
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
has the eigenvalues $3+\sqrt 5$ and $3-\sqrt 5.$

Assuming that for the same eigenvector of $A$, $A^t$ might have as eigenvalue the second one, one gets  $$A^tAv = A^t\lambda_1 v = \lambda_1 A^t v = \lambda_1 \lambda_2v,$$ meaning that $\lambda_1 \lambda_2$ is an eigenvalue of $A^tA.$ But this cant hold either as the example above shows it.

Can somebody explain where is the mistake ?

Comment: Matrices $A$ and $A^t$ have the same eigenvalues, but the eigenvectors are usually different. Therefore your first equality is not always true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$, it doesn't mean $v$ is an eigenvector of $A^\text{tr}$.

If $A$ is **symmetric** or **skew-symmetric**, though, then obviously $A$ and $A^\text{tr}$ have the same eigenvectors.

Answer (score 2):

In general, the eigenvalues of $A$ and $A^TA$ have nothing in common. For instance, the matrix

$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 &1\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

has one zero eigenvalue with algebraic multiplicity two. On the other hand

$$A^TA=\begin{bmatrix} 0 &0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

which has an eigenvalue at one. This shows that, in general, one cannot infer anything on the eigenvalues of $A^TA$ from those of $A$.

In the special case where the matrix $A$ is symmetric, then the eigenvalues of $A^TA=A^2$ are the square of the eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: In that case, we have that $B^{-1}=(A^TA)^{-1}=A^{-1}A^{-T}$. Using the fact that, for two square matrices $M,N$ with identical dimensions, the eigenvalues of $MN$ are the same as those of $NM$, one can conclude that the eigenvalues of $B^{-1}=A^{-1}A^{-T}$ are the same as those of $A^{-T}A^{-1}$. So, in the end the eigenvalues of  $A^{-T}A^{-1}$ are the inverse of those of $B$.

Comment: I deleted the question. Given the eigenvalues of $B = A^t A,$ what can we say about the eigenvalues of $(A^{-1})^t A^{-1}$ ? Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Similar matrices have same eigen values but they may not have same eigen vectors.
Any matrix is similar with its Transpose
All eigen values are same but eigen vectors may not be same.